# How to force http:// in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this in my htaccess file to force https on all pages on my sign in and sign up pages:

```
# Force https://
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond $1 ^(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I want to force http whenever the page is not sign in or sign up. How do I do that?

EDIT 1:

I actually need to do the following:

1. Force `https://` for pages in `sign-up` and `sign-in`
2. Force `http://` for pages not in `sign-up` and `sign-in`
3. Remove `www`
4. Remove `index.php`

The relevant part of my .htaccess has this:

```
#
# Force https:// or http://
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond $1 ^(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #RewriteCond $1 !^(sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sign-in|sign-up)(/|$) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

#
# Supress "www" at the beginning of URLs. Source: HTML5 Boilerplate
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

#
# Supress "index.php"
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why do you want to force http:// in the first place? Whenever your .htaccess is accessed, the client has already established the TLS session, so it doesn't cost you anymore.

Comment: I want to keep `https` to a minimum so I can leverage and maximize proxy caching.

Answer (score 1):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force HTTPS for sign-in|sign-up
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(sign-in|sign-up)(/|$) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]

# force HTTP for NOT sign-in|sign-up
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sign-in|sign-up)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm also trying to remove `index.php` and `www`. I think there are conflicts somehow. I will edit my post to show the entire mod_rewrite.

Comment: I don't see my suggested changed in your code. Have you tried these 2 rules?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, I have tried your suggestion. It doesn't work. Forcing `http` seems to work. However, forcing `https` does not. I think there might be some sort of conflict because when I go to a page that should have `https`, the URL ends up getting `index.php` (which should be suppressed by the other mod_rewrite rules).

Comment: OK Can you post you latest updated htaccess in your question.

Comment: I have posted my current htaccess in my question. When I replaced mine with yours, I had the problems.

Comment: Sorry, this is now causing even more problems. When I go to a sign in or sign up, I get a 404.shtml. When I go to a non-sign in or non-sign up page, it says "The requested URL /search/ was not found on this server." Why did you change the conditions/rules for "www" and "index.php"?

Comment: I'd rather not change the conditions/rules for "www" and "index.php". They seem to be working well. Forcing "https" also works well. Now, I just need to force "http".

Comment: Ok I got confused by your edited question that has all the 4 requirements listed. I rolled back my changes. Now which part is not working for your `forcing http` OR `forcing https`?

Comment: Forcing http does not work. Removing "www", removing "index.php" and forcing "https" works. So, my current htaccess does everything except force "http".

Comment: ok can you open Firebug and run `https://domain.com/` and see what you get in Net tab.

Comment: `200 OK`. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: hmm yes, just wanted to make sure it is not 301 twice.

Comment: When I go to `https://domain.com/sign-up/`, I get a 200 OK. When I go to `http://domain.com/sign-up/`, I get a 301, then 200.

Comment: But `https://domain.com/sign-up/` should remain `https` by definition.  And 301 & 200 for `http://domain.com/sign-up/` is also good because as per our rules it should be `https` for `/sign-up`. **I just wanted to know what happens in FIrebug when you open `https://domain.com/`**

Comment: Correct. I just posted all that info to show that everything else is working. The only thing that doesn't work is forcing `http://` when it's not sign in or sign up. Any ideas?

Comment: Right so when you enter `https://domain.com/` in Firebug does it just return `200` and no `301`? Also are you sure there is same `DocumentRoot` location in the `VirtualHost` entries for both http and https of your Apache config?

Comment: Just `200`, no `301` when I go to https://domain.com. I don't know about Apache config. I'm only messing with htaccess.

Comment: Please be specific. Did you open `https://domain.com/` OR `http://domain.com/` when you received 200? I am not suggesting any Apache config change but like to know whether https is configured correctly and when you open `https://domain.com/` request is coming to same .htaccess we're working on. That's why it is important to know the answer of the question in my previous comment.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check `VirtualHost` of `https` site?

Comment: Sorry, per my previous response, I get a `200 OK` when I go to `https://domain.com/`

Comment: ok but did you check `VirtualHost` entry of `https` site to see what is its `DocumentRoot` value.

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented this kind of solution personally (I have tended to use the PHP solution, like the one above, for it's simplicity), but the following may be, at least, a good start.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Check for POST Submission
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$

# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# Pages to Apply
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_secure [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_else_secure
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Forcing HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
# Pages to Apply
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_public [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^something_else_public
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I do not want to list all the "public" pages. I want to only say "not sign in or not sign up". How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to track the states you need and then only issue one redirect if necessary.

The following block should do exactly what you want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Define default protocol for all assets
   RewriteRule ^ - [E=protocol:http,E=ssl:%{HTTPS}off]

   # Define HTTPS targets, add more cond as required
   RewriteCond $1 (sign-in|sign-up) [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) - [E=protocol:https,E=ssl:%{HTTPS}on]

   # Rewrite host if necessary and redirect on correct protocol
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:protocol}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # Protocol switch if necessary (host is already correct)
   RewriteCond %{ENV:ssl} ^(onoff|offon)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:protocol}://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   # Finally, process the internal redirect
   RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

In this configuration, the **protocol** environment variable is used to track the actual protocol name to use and the **ssl** environment variable is the test to check if we are already on the correct protocol for the URI.

Using environment variables gives you 2 advantages :

- you avoid redirection chains. This configuration will redirect the user-agent at most once.
- you're DRY (Don't repeat yourself). Each condition is only expressed once, so it's easier to maintain.

Comment: Kindda works. If I go to `http://domain.com/sign-up/", the URL changes to `https://domain.comsignup/` (it's missing a slash after the domain). How to fix?

Comment: Also, if I go to `https://domain.com/foo/`, the URL change to `http://domain.comfoo/`

Comment: I've edited the response to work in both htaccess and main config using REQUEST_URI rather than captured content, this should address the missing / issue.

Comment: I think this has had some unintended side effects. A lot of my images, CSS and JS are referenced without a protocol (e.g. `//domain.com/assets/css/foo.css`). The idea is that they'll use the appropriate protocol, especially when on `https`. I think the .htaccess is now forcing those resources to use `http` (since they do not come from "sign-up" or "sign-in"). Thoughts?

Comment: There are lots of way to handle them correctly: exclude them based on extension, exclude any file that actually exists on disk, only include well-known extensions in your redirect (like html or php) or decide based on referrer protocol. Without knowledge of your application, it's hard to give you the best answer. I've updated the answer to exclude based on extension but it's just one of many possibilities

Comment: I see that you added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ [NC]`. This probably could work for me. However, not all my resources have a file extension (due to the way the CMS handles these files). I could possibly hack it a bit so that the files are forced to have file extensions. However, it there a way to do this via MIME type?

Comment: Yes but it would be inefficient because the server would have to do an additional sub-request to first find out the response content-type